# How can we use dangerouslySetInnerHTML with read-more-react - npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

how can we set dangerouslySetInnerHTML in text field, it shows error.

```
  <ReadMoreReact text={yourTextHere}
            min={minimumLength}
            ideal={idealLength}
            max={maxLength}
            readMoreText={readMoreText}/>
```

in the "yourtexthere" i want to add dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Answer (score 0):

if you are receiving htmlString then you can add read more button Without using read more react package.

Wrap up your content in a div and add maxheight and overflow property to the div.

now add show more or less button at the end handle the values from the state to update div
property maxheight  and overflow

Hope this help you out worked for me. Feel free to ask if you don't get it.

Comment: Some example code would be helpful!